# C# - Get html contents

Tags: c#

Hello 
How can I get a html content like a shoutbox or just the username of user connected in C# ?

Example: `<p><?php echo USER['name'] ?></p>`
in C#: How can I get the **p** value ?

Comment: You mean how you can get the value between `<p>` and `</p>` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want.

Comment: So here, you wanna get `<?php echo USER['name'] ?>` ?

Comment: Yes, I wanna get the username.

Comment: Well, if you wanna get the actual username and not `<?php echo USER['name'] ?>` it is not possible. It would mean that you would have to execute the PHP inside the CLR.

Comment: No, for an example I wanna get your username, here Marcus, How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an html parser like [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) .Regex is not a good choice for parsing HTML files as HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format.

You can use below code to retrieve it using HtmlAgilityPack

`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")//this xpath selects all p tags
                  .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                  .ToList();
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Give the P element an ID, and reference it by:

```
string contents = yourId.Text;
```

with your html like this:

```
<p id="yourId"></p>
```

Comment: In C#, yourId.Text mean what ?

Comment: yourId.Text is the way to access the text inside the element with the id "yourId". You might need to add some asp: tags in front of the p (Like this: <asp:p id=yourId></p>

Comment: No, you don't understand, I don't understand what yourId.Text is equal to which type in C# ?
If I write simply contents = yourId.Text, yourId.Text is not declared

Comment: It's a string (as seen in the example)